# python blockchain api to check balance with api key

Tags: python, blockchain, block

blockchain have limit for free checking and i have api how can i use api  for checking balance ?

where i must use api key ?

```
import requests
import re
file = open('wallet.txt', 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
    wallet = line.strip('\n')
    try:
        url = "https://blockchain.info/balance?active="+wallet
        r = requests.post(url)
        html = r.content
        mm= re.search('_balance"\:(.*?)\,"n_tx"', html)
        a1= mm.group(1)
        bb= re.search('_received"\:(.*?)\}\}', html)
        a2= bb.group(1)
        print ip+" Final balance : "+a1+" Total Received :"+a2
        aaa= ip+",Final balance : ,"+a1+",Total Received :,"+a2
        with open ('ousdt.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(aaa)+'\n')
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: You probably need to provide the key as a `post` method parameter.

Comment: how /? you have a sample?